# Calculating average of last 5 values whilst ignoring blank values whilst matching against a name criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to generate an Excel formula that averages the last 5 number values from Column G and matching against the name in Column B, whilst ignoring any blank cells to calculate the last 5 values of cells that have a number.

For example, the data is formatted like so:

```
John Smith     100
Adam Pratt      95
Michael Keen    86
John Smith      56
John Smith      78
John Smith      92
John Smith      88
```

I want to be able to calculate the average of the last values for 'John Smith'.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no version restrictions, as evidenced by your tags, you can use:

```
=AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER(B1:B100,A1:A100="John Smith"),-5))
```

- `FILTER` returns only the items in Col B that match with John Smith
- `TAKE`  with `-5` as the rows argument returns up to the last five items
- `AVERAGE` => the average of those five items

Since you don't indicate what you want to happen if there are fewer than five items, this formula will average whatever is there. If you want something else to happen, you will need to alter the formula.

If you want to dynamically create an output table with each of the names and their corresponding averages (up to a maximum of the last five elements, then you can use this formula in a single cell, and the results will SPILL to the output range:

```
=LET(
    x, UNIQUE(
        FILTER($A$1:$A$100, A1:$A$100 <> "")
    ),
    y, BYROW(
        x,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            AVERAGE(
                TAKE(
                    FILTER(
                        $B$1:$B$100,
                        $A$1:$A$100 = arr
                    ),
                    -5
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    HSTACK(x, y)
)
```

[image]

Comment: the `AVERAGE(TAKE` is the best one + 10 ☺

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I create a similar sample in column A and column B.

I suggest you use the formula to get the first cell of 'John Smith' in column A.

`="A"&LARGE(IF($A$1:$A$8=$A$8,IF(ISNUMBER($B$1:$B$8),ROW($A$1:$A$8)-ROW($A$1)+1)),5)`

[image]

The same for column B.

`="B"&LARGE(IF($A$1:$A$8=$A$8,IF(ISNUMBER($B$1:$B$8),ROW($A$1:$A$8)-ROW($A$1)+1)),5)`

[image]

Then the average value can use `=SUMIF(INDIRECT(E1):A8,A8,INDIRECT(E2):B8)/5` formula.

[image]

Comment: You are worked with little old school method but is nice one ,, + 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

- I'm assuming that your data is in `A2:B8`.
- You may use this formula which works with ALL VERSIONS of Excel.

  ```
  =IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A8,"John Smith",B2:B8,"<>")>=5,AVERAGE(IF((A2:A8="John Smith")*(B2:B8<>""),LARGE(B2:B8*(A2:A8="John Smith"),{1,2,3,4,5}))), "")
  ```
- You get answer `82.80`.

**N.B.** Adjust cell references as needed.